# DELETED: Deleted account when looking up robot. Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

We are having an issue when we are trying to create Web App to our Flutter project on firebase. If we try to create the Web Application using Firebase console this error appears:

[image: error]

If we try the same using `flutterfire configure` we get the same output error in **firebase-debug.log** file. We have 2 different firebase projects, in "development project" we aren't having any issue, but this is happening only in the "production project". We **haven't** deleted any account and the production project haven't been edited or reconfigured. If you need more info I'll provide it as soon as possible. Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!